# Selection sort implementation in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

Here's an implementation of selection sort, that sorts an array in ascending order.

Please let me know of any improvements/optimisations that can be done.

```
import java.util.List;

public class SelectionSort {

    public static void start(List<Integer> arrayToSort){
        for(int i = 0; i < arrayToSort.size(); i++) {   // i = leftmost index of unsorted part of the array
            int minimumValue = i;
            for(int j = i; j < arrayToSort.size(); j++){
                if(arrayToSort.get(j) < arrayToSort.get(minimumValue)){
                    minimumValue = j;
                }
            }
            swap(i, minimumValue, arrayToSort);
        }
    }


    private static void swap(int a, int b, List<Integer> arrayToSort){
        int temp = arrayToSort.get(a);
        arrayToSort.set(a, arrayToSort.get(b));
        arrayToSort.set(b, temp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you format

```
for(int i = 0; i < arrayToSort.size(); i++) {   // i = leftmost index of unsorted part of the array
```

as

```
// i = leftmost index of unsorted part of the array
for(int i = 0; i < arrayToSort.size(); i++) {
```

`swap` takes arguments `a`, `b` and `arrayToSort`. These arguments could be more explanatory: `swap` doesn't sort anything and it doesn't take an array, and `a` and `b` don't say much.

It's canonical to use `i` and `j` as indices, so that would be more appropriate - although longer names wouldn't hurt either. The `List` argument would be better as `items` or similar. `items` is `this`-like, so put it first.

```
private static void swap(List<Integer> items, int i, int j) {
    int temp = items.get(i);
    items.set(i, items.get(j));
    items.set(j, temp);
}
```

You can also make this more like the OpenJDK implementation by using the return value from `set`:

```
private static void swap(List<Integer> items, int i, int j) {
    int temp = items.set(i, items.get(j));
    items.set(j, temp);
}
```

or even

```
private static void swap(List<Integer> items, int i, int j) {
    items.set(j, items.set(i, items.get(j)));
}
```

You could also make it generic.

```
private static <T> void swap(List<T> items, int i, int j) {
    items.set(j, items.set(i, items.get(j)));
}
```

Your sort is of course inefficient; you're using selection sort. However, you can at least make it a little faster. First neaten it up - including changing the name to something more descriptive. Note that `minimumValue` is not a value but an index - this should be fixed.

```
public static void sortInPlace(List<Integer> toSort){
    // i = leftmost index of unsorted part of the array
    for(int i = 0; i < toSort.size(); i++) {
        int minimumValue = i;
        for(int j = i; j < toSort.size(); j++) {
            if(toSort.get(j) < toSort.get(minimumValue)) {
                minimumValue = j;
            }
        }
        swap(toSort, i, minimumValue);
    }
}
```

You can change the inner loop to start at `i + 1`. You can also cache the value to halve the number of `toSort.get`s you make.

```
public static void sortInPlace(List<Integer> toSort){
    // i = leftmost index of unsorted part of the array
    for(int i = 0; i < toSort.size(); i++) {
        int minimumIndex = i;
        int minimumValue = toSort.get(i);
        for(int j = i + 1; j < toSort.size(); j++) {
            if(toSort.get(j) < minimumValue) {
                minimumIndex = j;
                minimumValue = toSort.get(j);
            }
        }

        swap(toSort, i, minimumIndex);
    }
}
```

This gives a noticeable speed improvement.

Frankly, though, if you want a reasonably fast integer selection sort, use an array. `int[]` is unboxed, which means that it's some 4x the speed. It's actually faster to copy into a temporary `int[]`, sort and copy it back than to sort in a boxed `List`.

Comment: Oh wow. Thanks for this step-by-step feedback! I didn’t realise that there’s a 4x performance difference between arrays and `ArraysList`s. Do you know where I can find out more about this?

Also, is there a significant performance difference between caching the value and using `toSort.get()`? I understand that it’s better to cache the value because you want to make the algorithm as fast as possible.

Comment: "is there a significant performance difference between caching the value and using toSort.get()" → Indeed, it's about a factor of 2 for me. // `int[]` is faster because `int` is unboxed (just an integer) whereas `Integer` is boxed (a pointer to an `int`). `Foo[]` vs `List<Foo>` won't be as different since they both use `Foo`.